# Android App - Use System proxy settings for whole app

Tags: android, parse-platform, proxy, push-notification

I am currently deploying an app to a company that requires using their proxy for outbound http[s] connections. The issue I'm running into is my all of my requests I wrote work fine because I can make them use a proxy, however I'm using the Parse library for handling push notifications. When the user logs into the app it needs to setup the push sub on parse but cannot due to the app trying to use direct http connection to api.parse.com.

Is there a way to force all of the app to use the system proxy settings?

Is there another push library/service that would better suit my needs if not?

Thanks!